# When and which function is called to load resource for current page in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, localization

```
protected override void InitializeCulture()
{
    ...
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = frInfo;
    ...
}
```

We know we can set currentUICulture to make current page load language specific resource file. 
My questions are:
When and which function is called to load resource for current page in ASP.NET?
What is the internal mechnism of localizing a page?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you read the info found at this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163566.aspx).

Basically, you tell ASP.NET to load text from a user file in 3 ways:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="<%$ Resources:btnSubmit.Text %>" />
```

or

```
btnSubmit.Text = this.GetLocalResourceObject("btnSubmit.Text").ToString();
```

or, after you have created your entire page, you use the implicit resource binding:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" meta:resourcekey="btnSubmit" />
```

Implicit resource binding can be added very easily by going to Tools -> Generate Local Resource in visual Studio when you are in design view of an ASP.NET Page.